# Calling meta data in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata

So basically i am trying to edit a plugin called Showbiz. They call standard meta data from post like Title, Author, Date like this:

```
$title = $this->getValue("title");
$alias = $this->getValue("alias");
$urlImage = $this->imageUrl;
$text = $this->getValue("slide_text");

$link = $this->getValue("link");
if(empty($link))
    $link = "#";

$date = $this->getValue("date");

$dateModified = $this->getValue("date_modified");
$excerpt = $this->getValue("excerpt");

$youtubeID = $this->getValue("youtube_id");
$vimeoID = $this->getValue("vimeo_id");
$authorName = $this->getValue("author_name");
$numComments = $this->getValue("num_comments");
$catList = $this->getValue("catlist");
$tagList = $this->getValue("taglist");
$postID = $this->id;

//replace the items in the html
$html = $this->replacePlaceholder("title", $title, $html);
$html = $this->replacePlaceholder("id", $postID, $html);
$html = $this->replacePlaceholder("alias", $alias, $html);
$html = $this->replacePlaceholder("name", $alias, $html);
$html = $this->replacePlaceholder("image", $urlImage, $html);
$html = $this->replacePlaceholder("content", $text, $html);
$html = $this->replacePlaceholder("link", $link, $html);
$html = $this->replacePlaceholder("date", $date, $html);
$html = $this->replacePlaceholder("modified_date", $dateModified, $html);
$html = $this->replacePlaceholder("excerpt", $excerpt, $html);
$html = $this->replacePlaceholder("youtube_id", $youtubeID, $html);
$html = $this->replacePlaceholder("vimeo_id", $vimeoID, $html);
$html = $this->replacePlaceholder("author", $authorName, $html);
$html = $this->replacePlaceholder("numcomments", $numComments, $html);
$html = $this->replacePlaceholder("catlist", $catList, $html);
$html = $this->replacePlaceholder("taglist", $tagList, $html);
```

What I want to do is call my custom post type data. To do this in a normal template file I can add:

```
get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'META_DATA_NAME', true );
```

I am not sure how to add this to the template. I have tried adding the code below but got no value. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

```
$charity = $this->get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'META_DATA_NAME', true );

//replace the items in the html
$html = $this->replacePlaceholder("charity", $charity, $html);
```

Comment: Enter an exotic name in `title` or `alias`, like `StrackOverfrow`. Search the database. Now you have your `meta_data_name`.

Answer (score 0):

Does the getValue function work for ANY post meta or just those known to Showbiz? Have you tried ...

```
$charity = $this->getValue('META_DATA_NAME');
$html = $this->replacePlaceholder("charity", $charity, $html);
```